# gtalk Windows client trouble: permanent disconnect/reconnect

Tags: windows, google-talk

I have a trouble with my gtalk client on Windows. After signing in it's permanently starts disconnect/connect approximately each 1 minute. It's annoying and I don't understand what is the core of problem. This is observed on different Windows PC's, so it cannot be the problem of a specific PC. Waiting your help... Thanks

Comment: Try changing the password on your Google account?

Comment: @Kevdog777 - how is it connected to the password???

Comment: Well the first thing I thought of, was maybe someone has hacked in... I don't know - as you said it's not one PC specific.

Comment: Does this: http://help.trillian.im/discussions/windows/890-google-talk-keeps-disconnecting help at all?

Answer (score 0):

When you said "This is observed on different Windows PC's" , I can think of 2 things depending on what these different PC's are part of :

**1. These different PC's are part of the same home/office network :** 
In this case it would most likely be your internet connection that was going crazy. But on the other hand I suppose you would notice that since other internet applications would start to misbehave as well.

**2. The person you were having a conversation with reports the same issue :**
Then it is simply Google's server going berserk, which is(was) not a rare occurrence at all. Well by the time of writing this answer, I think the situation has improved substantially since you have posted the original question.

Take a look at [this resource](http://www.engadget.com/2012/07/26/google-talk-down-for-majority-of-users/) for example, to see that it is a "global phenomenon".

Now that Google-Talk has been replaced by Hangouts, you can follow [this website](http://downdetector.com/status/google-hangouts) in case such occurrence reappears and you want to know whether it's just your connection, or it is the application provider that has server issues. Or [this website](http://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=status&ts=1404079199000) for Google applications generally.

Answer (score 0):

Several months ago I found a solution - the gtalk server port should be set 80 instead of default ~5000. Now it works. Do not understand why nobody in community do not complain.